# Error adding to a array

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have used this method to add to arrays in other programs but this it doesn't seem to work. I am confused and can't find a answer to the problem.

Error:

```
The sample size is: Error using horzcat
CAT arguments dimensions are not consistent.
```

Error in CalculateElo (line 14)
    playerGroup = [playerGroup r];

Code:

```
function [accuracy] = CalculateElo (referenceElo , sampleSize, lower, upper)

fprintf('The sample size is: %d', sampleSize);

% Popoulate an new array
playerGroup = [];
playerGroup = [playerGroup referenceElo];

for i=1:(sampleSize - 1)
    %Create group size
    a = 0;
    b = 2000;
    r = (b-a).*rand(1000,1) + a;
    playerGroup = [playerGroup r];
end
```

Comment: `rand(1000,1)` is 1000 element row vecor. You cant add it to as a new column to  `playerGroup` if it has different number of rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An expression like `[x y]` tries to concatenate the arrays `x` and `y` along dimension 2. Each row of an array in Matlab must have the same length (similarly, each column must have the same length). Hence, if `size(x,1)` = `size(y,1)`, `[x y]` will return an array with size equal to `size(x,1)` along the first dimension and `size(x,2)+size(y,2)` along the second dimension. Otherwise you will get a `cat` error like the one you show.

`r` has size (1000,1), so unless the first dimension of `referenceElo` has size `1000`, you will get a `cat` error.

You didn't mention the size of `referenceElo`, but I'm guessing it's a single number. You could use the `'` (transpose) operator to write

```
playerGroup = [playerGroup r'];
```

returning an array of size (1,1001). Or you could use an expression of form `[x;y]`, which concatenates along dimension 1:

```
playerGroup = [playerGroup;r];
```

returning an array of size (1001,1).